# need help with php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have two files. one the sends out the curl post and another that receive the post, runs a query.

```
$curl = curl_init();                    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://url/filename.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "col1=data&col2=moredata");
$curlResult = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print_r($curlResult );
if($curlResult == "granted"){
echo 'right';
}else{
echo 'wrong';
}
```

the problem is even though the print_r shows 'granted' the if statement still fails. What am i missing? any help would be awesome.

Comment: Are you sure `curlResult` is a string?

Comment: well show us what the print_r() actually prints out.  Is it actually an array or something?  My first guess is to trim() it.

Comment: So you're getting the correct output just one row above the `if` statement? Try `trim`ing the result variable.

Comment: print_r displays "granted". exactly. i can also echo the variable and it displays "granted" not array or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER causes curl_exec() to return either false or a string.  So the question of whether or not it is an array is that it can't be, because it is a string.  Therefore, you most likely have newline or whitespace on there somewhere and need to [trim()](http://www.php.net/trim) it.